# Is a temperature change in quantum statistical dynamics related to a nonunitary evolution of the problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

Consider a quantum composite problem given in terms of a system $\hat{H}_s$ interacting via $\hat{H}_I$ with a bath $\hat{H}_B$ in terms of a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\hat{H}_s+\hat{H}_I+\hat{H}_B$. Furthermore, we consider the full initial density matrix as given by $\hat{\rho}(t=0)=|s><s|\otimes\hat{\rho}^{th}_B$, where we assume the system in an arbitrary system state $|s>$ and the bath in a thermal equilibrium state $\hat{\rho}^{th}_B=Z^{-1}(\beta)e^{-\beta\hat{H}_B}$.

**Question 1**

Does the unitary time-evolution of $\hat{\rho}(t)$ according to the Liouville-von Neumann equation $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho}=-\text{i}[\hat{H},\hat{\rho}]$ lead to thermalization of the system?

From my experience, I know thermalization can be studied by means of open-system Liouville von-Neumann equation, which results after tracing out the bath degrees of freedom (without going into details here, I assume the standard Lindblad form of the resulting Quantum Master equation)

$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\rho}_s
=
-\text{i}[\hat{H}_s,\hat{\rho}_s]
+
(1+\bar{n}(\beta))\mathcal{D}[\hat{\rho}_s]
+
\bar{n}(\beta)\mathcal{D}[\hat{\rho}_s].
$

The first term above governs the unitary evolution of the system, whereas the remaining two terms are related to the nonunitary evolution of the system. They induce thermal excitations and dissipation in the system due to the Dissipator $\mathcal{D}[\hat{\rho}_s]$.

**Question 2**

Why does it seem to be straightforward to attribute a change in temperature of the system to the non-unitary part of the reduced description, while this is just a implicit description of the problem questioned above?